# How to have results coming from a query in a JSON format?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, lambda

I am building a lambda on node.js and postgress database. When I query the database using :

```
client.query('SELECT name, age FROM user GROUP BY name')
```

I am getting an object like:

```
[['john', 35], ['mary', 26]]
```

what I want is to have on valid JSON, something like this:

```
[{"name" : "john", "age" : 35}, {"name" : "mary", "age" : 25}]
```

What is a good library or function that I can use to do this mapping? I tried JSON.parse and JSON.stringify but no luck. 
Of course I can write a function myself to build a JSON object and populate it with the values coming from database but I want to see if there is a better way to that.

Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make use of Postgres `array_to_json` and `array_agg` functions.

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(user_)) from user_;
```

This produces:

```
[{"name":"john","age":35},{"name":"mary","age":26}]
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=60bbc7683286fe11091865daeba261a6)

Comment: Thank you @Kaushik for the answer. I came across this solution however I was not sure if this will make the query expensive. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @DoArNa : I'm not sure about the performance aspect of it, but its way better than looping constructs. You may go ahead and explore other performant methods if there are any, but this method nonetheless is an elegant one.

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse through the array and make the desired `json` object

I put a sample code here

```
const myJsonObj = [];
const output = [['john', 35], ['mary', 26]];

for (let index=0; index<output.length; index++) {
    const user = output[index];
    const name = user[0];
    const age = user[1];
    myJsonObj.push({
        name: name,
        age: age,
    });
}

console.log(myJsonObj);
```

It will produce the desired output, you mentioned

> [ { name: 'john', age: 35 }, { name: 'mary', age: 26 } ]

Comment: Thanks for you answer Shams, however like I mentioned on my question, I know I can do it in this way but I was wondering if there is any library or function already built in that does this mapping.